# How to insert different images in ASP.NET MVC while using a foreachloop and a db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

```
<table class ="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Seafood</th>
        <th>Has Gluten</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
    </tr>

            @foreach (var items in @Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@items.ItemName</td>
                <td>@items.Price</td>
                <td>@items.IsSeafood</td>
                <td>@items.HasGluten</td>
            </tr>
            }
```

I am currently learning how to develop using ASP.NET MVC.

I am trying to insert different images for each of my items. My foreach loop creates the table and items from a mysql database. I want to add the pictures next to the tables unless I'm unable to with the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<img src=""/>` tag inside your last `<td>` to embed the image directly into the html.

Something like this, depending on how your image is stored.

```html
<td><img src="@items.Url"/></td>
```

Comment: That did let me add a picture but Im trying to figure out a way to do different pictures for each item. so since I have it my lib. I have it as <img src="/lib/Images/picture.jpg">. this runs the same picture for all items.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it depends on how your images are stored. If you put their paths somewhere in your items collection as a property then you can access it the way I showed.